# When i have a mysqli_multi_query followed by a mysqli_query, the second query fails

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, multi-query

I have a self calling php form that is supposed to update the database, then display the changes.  This is the general idea of what the code looks like:

```
IF($condition)
    mysqli_multi_query($dbc,$multiple_update_query_str);
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$select_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    echo    $row[0] . " " . $row[1] . " " . $row[2] . "<br>";
```

The first time, when the $condition is false, the select query works perfectly.  Then when the $condition is true, the update occurs on the database, but the select query fails.

My first thought was that php server was getting ahead of the mySQL server, so I used sleep(5) before exiting the if statement, but the select still failed.

I even wrote a very basic php file that was almost exactly this code.  It had the same problem.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you can use mysqli_query you must retrieve all the results of the multy_query to unlock the link connection

try:

```
if($condition){
    mysqli_multi_query($dbc,$multiple_update_query_str);
    while(mysqli_next_result($dbc)){;}
}
```

Comment: Except for the $ in front of the function, it worked perfect, Thanks!!

Comment: my bad, i adapted a OOP style code and forgot to erase the $. glad it helped